# grunt-autoprefixer setup

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, npm, autoprefixer

i'm very new to grunt (and npm in general) so forgive me if I've missed something glaringly obvious!

I'm trying to set up my gruntfile (which has been working just fine before I started this particular challenge) to use the autoprefixer plugin, I followed the instructions on this blog http://grunt-tasks.com/autoprefixer/ but I'm receiving this error when i try and initialize grunt :

```
 $ grunt

Running "postcss:dist" (postcss) task

Warning: Cannot read property 'postcss' of undefined Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

And here is my gruntfile :

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');

var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer-core');

require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

grunt.initConfig ({

uglify: {

my_target: {

files: {

'_/js/script.js' : ['_/components/js/*.js']

} //files

} //my_target

}, //uglify

compass: {

dev: {

options: {

config: 'config.rb'

} //options

}//dev

}, //compass

watch: {

options: {livereload: true},

scripts: {

files: ['_/components/js/*.js'],

tasks: ['uglify']

}, //script

sass: {

files: ['_/components/sass/*.scss'],

tasks: ['compass:dev']

}, //sass

html: {

files: ['*.html'],

}

}, //watch

postcss: {

options: {

processors: [

autoprefixer({

browers: ['> 0.5%', 'last 2 versions', 'Firefox ESR', 'Opera 12.1']

}).postcss

]

},

dist: {

files: {

'_/css/styles.css': '_/components/sass/*.scss'

}

}

}

}); //initConfig

grunt.registerTask('default', 'watch', ['postcss']);

} //exports
```

Am I missing something? (it's blatantly something stupid like a misplaced comma isnt it!!)
Thanks In advance

Comment: Can anybody help me with this problem? I'm really stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if anyone happens to stumble across this and has a similar problem here is my gruntfile that shows how i fixed the problem.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-postcss');
    grunt.initConfig ({
        uglify: {
            my_target: {
                files: {
                    '_/js/script.js' : ['_/components/js/*.js']
                } //files
            } //my_target
        }, //uglify
        compass: {
            dev: {
                options: {
                    config: 'config.rb'
                } //options
            }//dev
        }, //compass
        watch: {
            options: {livereload: true},
            scripts: {
                files: ['_/components/js/*.js'],
                tasks: ['uglify']
            }, //script
            sass: {
                files: ['_/components/sass/*.scss'],
                tasks: ['compass:dev']
            }, //sass
            html: {
                files: ['*.html'],
            }
        }, //watch
        postcss: {
            options: {
                map: true,
                processors: [
                    require('autoprefixer-core')({
                        browsers: ['last 2 versions']
                    })
                ]
            },
            dist: {
                src: '_/css/*.css'
            }
        }
    }); //initConfig
    grunt.registerTask('default', 'watch', ['postcss:dist']);
} //exports
```